# In xslt, select item with id, which value is in variable

Tags: xslt, sitecore, sitecore6

I have item ID as a variable. And in apply template I want to select Item with this ID. How can I do it? I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:variable name="myid"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Field',.,'id')"/> -//(this is Item ID)
</xsl:variable>      
<xsl:apply-templates mode="summary" select="sc:item('$myid',.)" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not enclose the variable reference in quotes:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="summary" select="sc:item($myid,.)" />
```

Note also that you can set the value of the variable directly like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myid" select="sc:fld('Target',.,'id')"/>
```